# Tridion 2011 event system - DCP

Tags: 2011, event-system

We're trying to catch the event when a DCP publishing action was committed successfully.

In the subscribe we have the following line of code:

```
_eventSubscriptions.Add(EventSystem.Subscribe<ComponentTemplate, SetPublishStateEventArgs>(OnComponentTemplateSetPublishedToTransactionCommitted, EventPhases.TransactionCommitted));
```

However, we never get into `OnComponentTemplateSetPublishedToTransactionCommitted`, while other similar events (e.g. Page publish) work fine.

Any idea what to change?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should you not be using `Component` instead of `ComponentTemplate` as your subject? To debug you could always set the subject as `RepositoryLocalObject` and see what happens when you publish a DCP

Comment: Hi Will, thanks for your feedback: Component did the trick for the DCP. But we now have a strange issue: SetPublishStateEvent events don't seem to be caught every time; looks like we only capture the events randomly. Rest of the events are always fired... Any idea?

Comment: Since Will answered the original question, consider starting another question showing your code, Kristof. That'll help determine if it's a setup issue or code-related.